# Word prediction / typing suggestions not available in Macbook Pro Touch Bar while working with MS Word

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Word prediction / typing suggestions is not available in Macbook Pro Touch Bar while working with MS Word.  Only formatting menu is appearing in the touch bar like Bold, Italics, Underline etc.

Answer (score 1):

Touch bar functionality is app specific and I don't currently see a way to customize the touch bar on Microsoft Word (it would be somewhere in the menu bar).